# Scaling SVG images in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, svg

I am having a problem where, when I scale an SVG in flex, it clips a part of the image, as shown below (the bottom right is clipped off, it should be rounded, like the top left)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" actionBarVisible="false"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Table">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout paddingTop="10"/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Embed(source="/assets/table.svg")]
            [Bindable]
            public var table:Class;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
        <s:Image source="{table}" width="50%" height="50%" verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0" scaleMode="stretch" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"/>
</s:View>
```

I can confirm, the SVG does not look like this, I have tried with many SVGs, and all have the same result...

**I want to have scalable images across my mobile application, over many devices and dpis, is this the best way to get scalable images?**

Cheers

**EDIT: SVG Code (Messy as straight export from Illustrator)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1024px"
     height="600px" viewBox="0 0 1024 600" enable-background="new 0 0 1024 600" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_2">
    <path fill="#3C2415" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M961,463.486c0,52.262-42.366,94.627-94.627,94.627H104.627
        C52.366,558.113,10,515.748,10,463.486V161.627C10,109.366,52.366,67,104.627,67h761.746C918.634,67,961,109.366,961,161.627
        V463.486z"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_1">
    <path fill="#006838" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M947.752,450.238c0,52.262-42.365,94.627-94.626,94.627H119.767
        c-52.261,0-94.626-42.365-94.626-94.627V175.821c0-52.261,42.366-94.627,94.626-94.627h733.359
        c52.261,0,94.626,42.366,94.626,94.627V450.238z"/>
    <path fill="#A97C50" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M457,248.5c0,37.832-30.668,68.5-68.5,68.5h-115
        c-37.832,0-68.5-30.668-68.5-68.5l0,0c0-37.832,30.668-68.5,68.5-68.5h115C426.332,180,457,210.668,457,248.5L457,248.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: is it only svg images that do this, or does the same thing happen with jpegs?

Comment: only seems to happen on svg images, cant work out why. svg created in illustrator

Comment: what's holding the view? `verticalCenter` and `horizontalCenter` should center the image (at least that's what happens when I pasted your code and replaced `<s:View>` with `<s:Application>`

Comment: Its part of a <s:s:ViewNavigatorApplication/> Ye, I wouldn't worry about the verticalCenter stuff, if I put the <image/> within a <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%"/> it centres fine

Comment: Can you use an FXG Image instead of an SVG Image?  I've done a bunch of work with FXG Images for my game ( https://market.android.com/details?id=air.com.igorKnots.magondaMaze&hl=en ) with pretty positive results.

Comment: Please post a link to the SVG . . . or you could just put the SVG code in your question, since it's XML based.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, Ive not done much research into FXG tbh, can you make FXG in photoshop or illustrator, how did you do it? The graphics look slick. Also, added SVG code, its messy as its from illustrator...

Comment: @Phil McP I can honesty say a designer did 90% the graphic creation.  I just did some minor mods in Illustrator and then did a "Save As" to create the FXG files.  I'm pretty sure Photoshop [and Fireworks] have similar options. I use FXG for the background of some of the screens and all the actual gameplay elements are FXG images. A lot of my presentation for the next 360|Flex will focus on this stuff

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and go along with Flextras on this one, FXG might be a better way to go.  I was able to replicate what you're seeing in an AIR desktop app, it appears there might be a problem with the height and width assigned in the svg.  I tried to validate by using some circle SVG from w3schools, it appears the initial size makes a difference in the display and the scaling is being done on a bitmap after it's been rendered.  Its probably best to test with simple shapes http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_examples.asp

Comment: @shaunhusain so by using simple SVG's, they worked fine and showed the entire image?

Comment: Yah I was able to get a circle to appear in the correct position and to scale, but it appeared to be scaling the already rendered bitmap data rather than scaling and drawing at the new scale which is what I was personally expecting (still got grainy lines when upping the size).  For simple shapes it'd almost certainly work better if you use the new mxml graphics since I'm almost positive these will scale well http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4D7543E0-0BA2-4f5f-92FA-985B6B6315AB.html

Comment: For more complex drawings exporting to FXG I believe is the way to go.  It's strange because when I open your SVG in internet explorer it looks fine but in Flex as the source of an image it always gets bumped down from the top to some degree, unfortunately I don't know SVG well enough to decipher the path definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I finally settled on - works with FXG, SVG, and raster images as well.  For the record I stole most of this from somewhere, and made a bunch of edits to make it work correctly. Also, make sure in Illustrator you resize the artboard to fit the selected artwork, then on the export options for SVG uncheck all the BS and turn off the adobe preview crap as well.

```
package Core.Controls
{
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

import mx.core.UIComponent;

import spark.primitives.Rect;

public class VectorImage extends UIComponent
{
    public function VectorImage(source:Class = null)
    {
        if(source){
            this.source = source;
        }
        super();
    }

    private var _source : Class;
    protected var sourceChanged :Boolean = true;


    public function get source():Class
    {
        return _source;
    }

    public function set source(value:Class):void
    {
        _source = value;
        sourceChanged = true;
        this.commitProperties();
    }

    protected var imageInstance : DisplayObject;


    override protected function createChildren():void{
        super.createChildren();

        // if the source has changed we want to create, or recreate, the image instance
        if(this.sourceChanged){
            // if the instance has a value, then delete it
            if(this.imageInstance){
                this.removeChild(this.imageInstance);
                this.imageInstance = null;
            }

            // if we have a source value; create the source
            if(this.source){
                this.imageInstance = new source();
                this.addChild(this.imageInstance);
            }
            this.sourceChanged = false;

        }
    }

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override protected function commitProperties():void{
        super.commitProperties();

        if(this.sourceChanged){
            // if the source changed re-created it; which is done in createChildren();
            this.createChildren();
        }
    }

    override protected function measure():void
    {
        if(imageInstance != null)
        {
            this.measuredWidth = imageInstance.width;
            this.measuredHeight = imageInstance.height;
            this.minWidth = 5;
            this.minHeight = 5;
        }
    }

    override public function setActualSize(width:Number, height:Number):void
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        ScaleImage(width, height);
    }

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void{
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        // size the element.
        // I don't remember why I Wrote the code to check for unscaledHeight and unscaledWidth being 0

        if(imageInstance != null)
        {

            //scale properly
            ScaleImage(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        }
    }

    protected function ScaleImage(width:Number, height:Number)
    {
        if(imageInstance != null)
        {
            var scale:Number = Math.min(width/imageInstance.width, height/imageInstance.height);

            var scaleWidth:Number = (int)(imageInstance.width * scale);
            var scaleHeight:Number = (int)(imageInstance.height * scale);

            imageInstance.width = scaleWidth;
            imageInstance.height = scaleHeight;

            imageInstance.x = (width - imageInstance.width) *.5;
            imageInstance.y = (height- imageInstance.height) *.5;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this

```
<s:Image source="{table}" width="50%" height="50%"
```

You are sizing the image to 50% of the container it is in.

Try something like this.

```
<s:Image source="{table}" width="{table.width}" height="{table.height}"
```

or just take out width and height altogether.

Worst case you will have to size the image when the scale is changed.

Comment: unfortunately changing the height doesn't solve the problem. Ive tried adding the SVG in a number of different scenarios, thanks anyway

Comment: In your posted image you can plainly see the image is getting clipped at 50% of the canvas size. right-left and top-bottom. Did you even to change the values or height and width? Again trust me I have been through this. the scaling is causing it to be masked.

Comment: It really seems as if @The_asMan was right. Looking at your screenshot, I would focus on the 50% values

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want is:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
width="100%" height="100%" 
viewBox="0 0 1024 600" 
preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
```